# How do I find out which users with a specific RoleID that's not been active within a time interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query down below will tell me how many non-active users there's been during a timeframe.

```
USE Database
SELECT u.*
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Users] u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] ct
                  WHERE c.tUserID = u.UserID AND ct.CreationDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
             );
```

And this query below will tell me the users that have the specific role id I'm looking for.

```
Use Database;

SELECT UserID, DepartmentID, RoleId
FROM tbl_UsersBelongsTo
WHERE RoleID=6
```

How can I integrate both queries and essentially get what I'm looking for? I presume it's with a `JOIN` clause but how??

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `join` or additional `exists`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Users] u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] ct
                  WHERE ct.tUserID = u.UserID AND
                        ct.CreationDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
             ) AND
     EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM tbl_UsersBelongsTo ubt
             WHERE ubt.RoleID = 6 AND ubt.userId = u.userId
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use an inner join like below:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Users] u
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT UserID
   FROM tbl_UsersBelongsTo
   WHERE RoleID=6
) x ON u.UserID = x.UserID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [dbo].[CaseTable] ct
                  WHERE c.tUserID = u.UserID AND ct.CreationDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' 
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about `JOINS` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

If I understood the question correctly - you are using 2 different databases and the name of the 2nd database is `pisacara`. It is possible to join tables from different databases in SQL Server as long as as those databases are on the same server and you use the same credentials for both databases.

Assuming that `tbl_Users` table has a `UserID` field as well, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM [1st_database_name].[dbo].[tbl_Users] u
INNER JOIN [piscara].[dbo].[tbl_UsersBelongsTo] a
ON u.UserID = a.UserID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [1st_database_name].[dbo].[CaseTable] ct
                  WHERE c.tUserID = u.UserID 
                  AND ct.CreationDate BETWEEN'2019-01-01' AND'2019-12-31' 
             )
AND a.RoleID=6;
```

You can also try putting the 2nd query in the `WHERE` clause, as a sub-query, like so:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM [1st_database_name].[dbo].[tbl_Users] u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [1st_database_name].[dbo].[CaseTable] ct
                  WHERE c.tUserID = u.UserID 
                  AND ct.CreationDate BETWEEN'2019-01-01' AND'2019-12-31' 
             )
AND u.UserID IN (SELECT UserID
                FROM [piscara].[dbo].[tbl_UsersBelongsTo]
                WHERE RoleID=6);
```